# Error while writing file to Amazon S3 bucket NoSuchFieldERROR INSTANCE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-httpcomponents

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
                try {
                    ByteArrayInputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(barry);
                    ObjectMetadata obkmeta = new ObjectMetadata();
                    obkmeta.setContentType("image/jpg");
                    obkmeta.setContentLength(barry.length);
                    //s3Client.putObject(SAAStoken, fileStoreFolderURL+ filename, dataStream, obkmeta);
                    s3Client.putObject(SAAStoken, "mediarepo/SessionFile/"+ filename+".jpg", dataStream, obkmeta);
                } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
                }
```

[image]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**I have tried upgrading versions. Please help

1. Upgraded httpclient version
2. Same piece of code working in another project

**

Comment: HttpClient and HttpCore have distinct release cycles. HttpClient 4.5 requires HttpCore 4.4. Use the latest version of HttpClient 4.5.x and the latest version of HttpCore 4.4.x

Comment: Use the recommended SDK version. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/PutObject.java

Comment: I have tried updating httpclient and httpcore version to latest version but still not working